# Pegando Output History do Terminal no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Existe alguma forma de pegar o Output History do terminal do Ubuntu?
Como um log de tudo o que rolou em um terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, nao fica muito agradavel de ler, mas funciona:

Antes de comecar a usar o terminal (e assumindo que voce usa `bash`, que e o shell padrao no Ubuntu):

```
bash | tee bash.output
```

No fim, voce vai ter um arquivo `bash.output` no seu `home` com a saida, mas tudo junto, sem mostrar de onde veio cada coisa.

Comment: O comando `history` retorna todos os inputs que eu fiz no terminal. Eu não quero os inputs, eu quero os outputs

Comment: Opa, perdao. Li errado.

Comment: Agora sim :P Perdao pela 'resposta' anterior.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, já estou usando o terminal e quero pegar o histórico dele. Meu cenário atual, eu estou tentando replicar um erro de um sistema em python. Hoje de manhã eu consegui replicar o erro mas não salvei o traceback, tenho como recuperar esse traceback? Ainda estou com a janela do terminal aberta.

Comment: Ah, voce quer dizer algo que aconteceu no passado? Acho que nao tem como :(

Comment: =/ Vou deixar a thread aberta e ver se aparece algum milagre por aqui.

Comment: @jpklzm fiquei pensando hoje em um modo de fazer o que voce gostaria (de pegar o resultado de comandos do passado), mas cheguei a conclusao que nao faria sentido. por mais que voce pudesse fazer um script que refizesse todos os comandos no `.bash_history`, alguns desses comandos nao tem output, ou nao vou funcionar (algo como um `cd dir` que dir nao esta no local certo). ou seja, acho que o milagre nao existe XD

Comment: É uma pena, seria algo muito útil.

Answer (score 1):

Há um outro meio e não posso deixar de comentar.
Na pasta pessoal há um arquivo chamado .bash_history(/home/usuário/.bash_history). Se você abrir pelo nautilus, dê um ctrl+h para exibir os arquivos ocultos e você o encontrará. Se quiser ver diretamente no shell, digite:

```
cat /home/username/.bash_history | more
```

Aperte enter para exibir os seguintes.

Comment: esse arquivo so mostra os inputs, o op queria a saida dos comandos.

Comment: Realmente. Falhei ao analisar a questão e alguns dos comentários.

Comment: idem XD foi basicamente a minha aula primeira resposta :)

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada melhor sobre isso. Para ter as saídas gravadas parece que deve-se configurar isso previamente.

Answer (score 1):

Output de um terminal:

**H1**) definir uma história de terminal comprida, e fazer cut&paste do terminal para um ficheiro

**H2**) usar o comando `script file` (guarda a sessão em `file`) -- script 
tem várias opções que podem ser uteis.

**Edição** mais detalhadamente:

H1) o terminal mantem uma história acessível pela scroll-bar (por omissão 512 linha, configurável no profile do terminal). 
Se, usando o rato selecionarmos a saída pretendida podemor fazer cut&paste
dentro do teu editor preferido.

H2) o commando **script** foi criado para questões como a levantada nesta pergunta. (ver `man script`); experimenta

```
script log
... executar alguns comandos
(CTR-D)
... e vê o conteudo do ficheiro log
```

Comment: Não entendi nada, pode elaborar melhor sua resposta?

Comment: @jpklzm, vê se a edição ajudou. (o que é que concretamente está difícil de entender?)